# What is river kauthar mentioned in Surah108 of Quran?

Tags: quran

What is River Kauthar, mentioned in Surah 108 of Quran. Where it is located and Why Muhammad (pbuh) will make his ummah to drink its water on the day of judgment? And who will be deprived from drinking it?

Answer (score 1):

**اِنَّاۤ اَعۡطَيۡنٰكَ الۡكَوۡثَرَؕ**
**Indeed, we have given you Al-Kauthar (a river in paradise; the abundance).**

(Surah Kauthar:1)
Kauthar means unbounded and limitless abundance of good, spiritual benefits and blessings.

Enemies of prophet PBUH always tried to defame him by saying that let him alone for he is only a childless man with no male offspring. When he dies, there will be no one to remember him." Under such disturbing condition surah Kauthar was sent down.

It was narrated that Anas in Malik said:

***"One day when he-the Prophet (ﷺ)- was still among us, he took a nap, then he raised his head, smiling. We said to him: 'Why are you smiling, O Messenger of Allah?' He said: 'Just now this Surah was revealed to me: In the Name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful. Verily, We have granted you (O Muahmmad) Al-Kawthar. Therefore turn in prayer to your Lord and sacrifice (to Him only). For he who hates you, he will be cut off.' Then he said: 'Do you know what Al-Kawthar is?' We said: 'Allah and His Messenger know best.' He said: 'It is a river that my Lord has promised me in Paradise…”***

(An-Nasai: 904, Abi Dawud 784).
The river Al Kauthar is situated in the eighth Garden of paradise, called the dome of garden and Abode of Rest with a running field in the judgment day.

It was narrated from Ibn ‘Umar that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

***“Kauthar is a river in Paradise whose banks are of gold and its bed is of rubies and pearls. Its soil is more fragrant than musk, its water is sweeter than honey and whiter than snow.”***

(Ibn Majah 4334)

Anas bin Malik narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) was asked:

***"What is Al-Kawthar?" He said: "That is a river that Allah has given me"- that is, in Paradise- 'whiter than milk and sweeter than honey. In it are birds whose necks are like the necks of camels." 'Umar said: "Indeed this is plump and luxurious then." So the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said, "Those who consume it are more plumb than it.***"

(Tirmidhi 2542)

Imagine the birds with the neck of camel. Don’t these words refer to the concept of genetic engineering or genetic modification in the current age? Researchers said that a time will come when a person can buy a thing according to his own choice in the market, i. e., I want to buy a cow with the neck of a giraffe.

Anyhow, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) further said that:

Narrated `Abdullah bin` Amr:

***The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "My Lake-Fount is (so large that it takes) a month's journey to cross it. Its water is whiter than milk, and its smell is nicer than musk (a kind of Perfume), and its drinking cups are (as numerous) as the (number of) stars of the sky; and whoever drinks from it, will never be thirsty."***

(Al-Bukhari 6579)

Have you ever thought that why whoever will drink from Kauther, will never be thirsty again? It is because when Adam and Eve A.S tasted the forbidden fruit against the warning
***“come not near this tree or you both will be of the Zalimeen (wrong-doers).”***

(Al- Baqarah: 35).

It has changed their body chemistry and causing thirst of desire. In the same way, when a person drink from Al- Kauthar, his body chemistry will also change and prepare him to face successfully the further stages of the day of judgment like Intercession, pull Sarat, Hell, paradise, etc.

Further Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said:

***….My Ummah will come to me, then a man among them will be pulled away and I will say: "O Lord, he is one of my Ummah" and He will say to me: 'You do not know what he did after you were gone."***

(An-Nasai: 904)

We all know that currently to what extent we are practicing Biddats (to invent new things in Deen) just on the name of modern lifestyle or by following our ancestors’ fake creeds. We are still practicing non-muslins traditions, customs and superstitions in our daily life.

The point to think is that have you ever imagine or feel the fear to be in such a situation when prophet Muhammad (pbuh) gives you a glass of Abbay Kauthar and you are about to drink it. But it is snatched by the angels who says that “O Muhammad (pbuh), you do not know what he did after you were gone?”

Think carefully and deeply for a moment, if such happens, what will we do?